# Uniqueness of a solution of $\ x' = Ax + b(t) \ $ that tends to $0$ in $+\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $b : [0,+\infty) \to \mathbb R^n$ continuous and integrable. Prove there exists an unique solution of $x' = Ax + b(t)$ that tends to $0$ in $+\infty$ with $A \in M_n{(\mathbb R)}$.

I don't really see how to deal with this problem if not to integrate the equation. Is not a condition on $A$ needed?

If a condition is needed, then it would be $A$ is antisymmetric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skew-symmetric is the key here.

If $A$ is skew symmetric then $e^{At}$ is orthogonal, hence uniformly bounded
for all $t$.

The solution is $x(t) = e^{At} (x_0 + \int_0^t e^{-A s}b(s) ds ) $.

In particular, since $t \mapsto \|e^{At} b(t)\|$ is integrable, if we choose
$x_0 = - \int_0^\infty e^{-A s}b(s) ds $, we see that
$x(t) \to 0$.

Comment: Does this prove uniqueness?

Comment: Sure! In all cases, $\|x(t)\|  \to \|x_0+\int_0^\infty e^{-As} b(s) ds \|$, so there is exactly one $x_0$ (and hence exactly one solution) that satisfies the condition.